# Grand total of a row does not show up if a value in the row is zero in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query as seen below:

```
select t.pos_date 
,tltf.tax_rate as fet_rate 
,tltp.tax_rate as pft_rate 
,tltg.amount as gsthstfnt 
,tltf.tax_rate + tltp.tax_rate + tltg.amount as total_column


from transaction as t 
left outer join contract as c 
on t.contract_id = c.contract_id 
left outer join trans_info as tiu
```

The above query when executed gives me the below result:

[image]

As you can see from the image, the grand total `"total_column"` is being printed only when all the values are present.

My question is, how can I print the `total_column` even when some values are missing?

I have tried casting as shown below:

```
select t.pos_date 
,tltf.tax_rate as fet_rate 
,tltp.tax_rate as pft_rate 
,tltg.amount as gsthstfnt 
,cast(tltf.tax_rate as varchar(10)) + cast(tltp.tax_rate as int(10)) + tltg.amount as total_column
```

but nothing has worked out so far.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the whole thing in `COALESCE()` to handle `NULL`?  `COALESCE(tltf.tax_rate + tltp.tax_rate + tltg.amount,0) as total_column`

Comment: I just did a COALESCE(), but i see this:



pos_date      fet_rate        pft_rate    gsthstfnt         total_column
2016-01-14 14:01:00.0 0.04000 0.13000   0.00000

Comment: Whoops, I misread, let me write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that you can't do math on a `NULL`, which is causing issues when adding up the final column when at least one column is `NULL`.  You should `COALESCE()` all columns to handle this:

```
SELECT t.pos_date 
      ,COALESCE(tltf.tax_rate,0) as fet_rate 
      ,COALESCE(tltp.tax_rate,0) as pft_rate 
      ,COALESCE(tltg.amount,0) as gsthstfnt 
      ,COALESCE(tltf.tax_rate,0) + 
       COALESCE(tltp.tax_rate,0) + 
       COALESCE(tltg.amount,0) as total_column
```

I suppose it's really up to you if you handle `NULL` in the individual columns, but I tend to prefer seeing the `0` myself.

Comment: @Newbee NP, happy coding

Comment: If you are only evaluating one value, why not use `ISNULL(ColumnName, 0)`?

Comment: Nevermind!  Here is a good resource that nicely explains the difference between the two: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull

Comment: ISNULL being T-SQL specific would be the reason not to use it.